# Rank a date from oldest to newest SQL

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions, rank

This seems simple enough but my brain isn't working and thought I'd ask the group. I want to rank the dates in a a fashion similar to the table below. There are other fields in this table but if the date repeats, then the rank can also repeat for that same date as shown below for 12/31 and 1/5

| Date | Rank |
| --- | --- |
| 12/31/2020 | 1 |
| 12/31/2020 | 1 |
| 1/1/2021 | 2 |
| 1/2/2021 | 3 |
| 1/2/2021 | 3 |
| 1/3/2021 | 4 |
| 1/4/2021 | 5 |
| 1/5/2021 | 6 |
| 1/5/2021 | 6 |
| 1/7/2021 | 7 |
| 1/10/2021 | 8 |

Comment: Hey, Please check the answer and let me is that what you ask? If not then please edit your post and give a sample input and output.

Comment: Why is 2021-01-02 given two different ranks but other dates have only one?

Comment: @gordonLinoff. GOod catch. It should actually be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by date) as rank
from t;
```

This assumes that the issue with 2021-01-02 is a typo in the question.

If there are time components on the "date"s, then convert to a date for the ordering:

```
select t.*,
       dense_rank() over (order by convert(date, date)) as rank
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon . This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `DENSE_RANK` and `Distinct`. So, the query should be look like

```
 --Without Duplicate Dates
    Select Distinct YouDATE,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY YourDateColumn) MyRANK
    FROM YourTable;
--With Duplicate Dates
    Select YouDATE,
           DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY YourDateColumn) MyRANK
    FROM YourTable;
```

**Note:** This code is written in SQL SERVER. Please check and let me know.